# Specify color of the first row in table (in "newenvironment")

Tags: tables, color, environments

I am using an specific style for my tabulars and I am looking to specify automatically the color of the text in the first row.

Currently I must specify manually the color of the text of each cell in the row.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\newsavebox{\dataTableContent} % Box
\newenvironment{dataTable}[1] % \new environment
{%
\begin{lrbox}{\dataTableContent}%
\begin{tabular}{#1}}%
%
{%
\end{tabular}
\end{lrbox}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [inner xsep=0pt] (tbl){\usebox{\dataTableContent}};
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
% table
\draw[rounded corners=1pt,top color=gray!1,bottom color=gray!30,draw=black]
(tbl.north east) rectangle (tbl.south west);
% top line
\draw[rounded corners=1pt,top color=gray!10!black,bottom color=gray!50!black,draw=black]%
($(tbl.north west)$) rectangle ($(tbl.north east)-(0,1.5\baselineskip)$);
% bottom rule
\draw[rounded corners=0.25pt,fill=gray,draw=black]%
(tbl.south west) rectangle ($(tbl.south east)+(0,0)$);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\begin{dataTable}{lc}
\color{white}Rien&\color{white}tout\\\midrule
si&non
\end{dataTable}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

The idea to create the a table using classical commands:

```
\begin{dataTable}{lc}
Rien&tout\\\midrule
si&non
\end{dataTable}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Take a look at the `pgfplotstable` package, which offers a `pgfkeys` interface to change the formatting of certain rows, columns, and so on.

Comment: @Daniel I know the `pgfplotstable`package but the syntax is different than classical tabular and I want to keep classical command to define my table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a macro pair that adds the colour command to each cell in the first row:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\def\head#1\\{\shead#1&\\}
\def\shead#1&#2\\{\color{white}#1\ifstrempty{#2}{\\}{&\shead#2\\}}

\newsavebox{\dataTableContent} % Box
\newenvironment{dataTable}[1] % \new environment
{%
\begin{lrbox}{\dataTableContent}%
\begin{tabular}{#1}\head}%
%
{%
\end{tabular}
\end{lrbox}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [inner xsep=0pt] (tbl){\usebox{\dataTableContent}};
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    % table
    \draw[rounded corners=1pt,top color=gray!1,bottom color=gray!30,draw=black]
    (tbl.north east) rectangle (tbl.south west);
    % top line
    \draw[rounded corners=1pt,top color=gray!10!black,bottom color=gray!50!black,draw=black]%
    ($(tbl.north west)$) rectangle ($(tbl.north east)-(0,1.5\baselineskip)$);
    % bottom rule
    \draw[rounded corners=0.25pt,fill=gray,draw=black]%
    (tbl.south west) rectangle ($(tbl.south east)+(0,0)$);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{dataTable}{lcr}
Rien&tout&plus\\\midrule
si&non&oui\\
non&non&non
\end{dataTable}

\end{document}
```

I have defined a command `\head` that is placed at the beginning of the `tabular` inside your `dataTable` environment.  It calls a helper command `\shead` to insert the `\color{white}` command, using the pattern matching available from plain TeX's `\def`.